# Default browser IE

Tags: asp.net

I am using C# and ASP.net - Website

In my website, I need to set the IE browser by default for a particular page each day.
Is there any way to set it permanently?

Comment: You mean you want your website to somehow force a user's default browser to be IE? If so... you can't do that, and you *shouldn't want to*

Comment: Don't force users to use a specific web browser (if that is what you are doing). I use Linux, which leaves me without IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special treatment per page in visual studio. If you choose IE as default, then you have it for the entire project; it is also not permanent, changable whenever you want.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be asking about the browser built in to Visual Studio; he never mentions VS at all.

Comment: My only question is, I want to set the IE for all pages in debug mode not in release mode.